# Sort by multiple objects in a array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash, javascript-objects

```
var customersObj= [ 
    { recordId: "123", groupID: "1992" ,memberID:"10" Name : "John"     },
    { recordId: "141",  groupID: "1994" ,memberID:"13", Name : "Arrow"  },
    { recordId: "111", groupID: "1991",memberID:"12", Name : "Mike" }
];
```

I need to return the array by sort them first by `recordId`, then by `groupID`, then by `memberID` ...

I tried this but didn't get expected result"

```
return _.sortBy(customersObj,'recordID','groupID','memberID');
```

Can someone assist here on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention that your `*ID` are **string**s, so, I've used `Array.map` to convert them to ints, and then `_.sortBy` works expectedly.

I've added additional values to check the sub-sorting.

```js
const customersObj = [{
  recordId: "123",
  groupID: "1992",
  memberID: "10",
  Name: "John"
}, {
  recordId: "141",
  groupID: "1994",
  memberID: "13",
  Name: "Arrow"
}, {
  recordId: "111",
  groupID: "1991",
  memberID: "12",
  Name: "Mike"
}, {
  recordId: "123",
  groupID: "1991",
  memberID: "12",
  Name: "Sean"
}, {
  recordId: "123",
  groupID: "1991",
  memberID: "11",
  Name: "Sara"
}];

const result = customersObj.map(item => ({
  recordId: parseInt(item.recordId, 10),
  groupID: parseInt(item.groupID, 10),
  memberID: parseInt(item.memberID, 10),
  Name: item.Name
}));

console.log(_.sortBy(result, 'recordId', 'groupID', 'memberID'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks @felixmosh, but converting in to INT doesn't applicable for memberID with values more than six digits, for example the real data for member ID would be '1342493', '148005', '1808779'..So please advice how to sort with third value

Comment: JS supports 6 digits as ints...
max value is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991`

Answer (score 0):

Try use this approach:

```
const customersObj= [
  { recordId: "123", groupID: "1992" ,memberID:"10", Name : "John"     },
  { recordId: "141",  groupID: "1994" ,memberID:"13", Name : "Arrow"  },
  { recordId: "111", groupID: "1991",memberID:"12", Name : "Mike" }
];

const sorted = customersObj.sort((a,b)=>{
  return a.recordId - b.recordId || a.groupID - b.groupID || a.memberID - b.memberID;
})    

console.log(`sorted`, sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sort method with lambda function to sort.

```
const list = [
{      color: 'white', size: 'XXL' },
    { color: 'red', size: 'XL' },
   { color: 'black', size: 'M' }
]
list.sort((a, b) => (a.color > b.color) ? 1 : -1) // you can add different conditions here.
```

Answer (score 0):

to sort multiple fields, do it like this

```
customersObj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a["recordId"] - b["recordId"] || a["groupID"] - b["groupID"] || a["memberID"] - b["memberID"];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `array of object` using multiple values by the following method

```js
var arrayOfObj = [ 
    { recordId: "123", groupID: "1992" ,memberID:"10" , Name : "John"     },
    { recordId: "141",  groupID: "1994" ,memberID:"13", Name : "Arrow"  },
    { recordId: "111", groupID: "1991",memberID:"12", Name : "Mike" }
];

let sortBy = [{
  prop:'recordId',
  direction: 1
},{
  prop:'lastName',
  direction: 1
},{
  prop:'memberID',
  direction: 1
}];

arrayOfObj.sort(function(a,b){
  let i = 0, result = 0;
  while(i < sortBy.length && result === 0) {
    result = sortBy[i].direction*(a[ sortBy[i].prop ].toString() < b[ sortBy[i].prop ].toString() ? -1 : (a[ sortBy[i].prop ].toString() > b[ sortBy[i].prop ].toString() ? 1 : 0));
    i++;
  }
  return result;
})

console.log(arrayOfObj, ":::::");
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash,  could take an array of keys and take the right spelling of the wanted keys.

```js
var customersObj = [{ recordId: "123", groupID: "1992", memberID: "10", Name: "John" }, { recordId: "141", groupID: "1994", memberID: "13", Name: "Arrow" }, { recordId: "111", groupID: "1991",
memberID: "12", Name: "Mike" }];

console.log(_.sortBy(customersObj, ['recordId', 'groupID', 'memberID']));
//                                 ^        ^                        ^
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried solve your problem :)

```js
const display = document.querySelector(".display");

var customersObj= [ 
    { recordId: "123", groupID: "1992" ,memberID:"10", Name : "John"     },
    { recordId: "141",  groupID: "1994" ,memberID:"13", Name : "Arrow"  },
    { recordId: "111", groupID: "1991",memberID:"12", Name : "Mike" }
];
customersObj.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.recordId - b.recordId || b.groupID - a.groupID || c.memberID - c.memberID;
});
customersObj.map(obj => {
  const item = document.createElement("div");
  item.textContent += obj.recordId + " " + obj.groupID + " " + obj.memberID +" "+ obj.Name;
  display.appendChild(item);
});
```

```html
<div class="display">
</div>
```